# Output Multi Array to CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, export-to-csv

I want to write the following Array in a CSV file:

```
Array ( [0] => Array
    (
        [ean] => SportsBag1
        [condition] => 100
        [listing_price] => 39
        [minimum_price] => 39
        [amount] => 26
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ean] => SportsBag2
        [condition] => 100
        [listing_price] => 37
        [minimum_price] => 37
        [amount] => 17
    )
and so on...
```

CSV should look like this:

```
ean | condition | listing_price | minimum_price | amount
val | value     | value         | value         | value
val | value     | value         | value         | value
val | value     | value         | value         | value
```

right now theres everything in one column and the whole array look(with brackets and everything else) and not every value(plain data) in his own column
Theres a lot of threads on stackoverflow directed to this subject but nothing really can solve my problem.

I am using the following code:

```
//EDIT
$suchmuster = array();
$suchmuster[0] = '/&nbsp;/';
$suchmuster[1] = '/\s\s+/';
$suchmuster[2] = '/-150x150/';
$suchmuster[3] = '/-300x300/';
$suchmuster[4] = '/-500x500/';

$inventorydata = array();
$productdata = array();

while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

$product = get_product($loop->post);

$title = $product->get_title();
$link = get_permalink();
$descriptionunstripped = strip_tags($post->post_content); //EDIT
$description = preg_replace($suchmuster, ' ', $descriptionunstripped); //EDIT
$details = $post->the_excerpt;
$categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
$sku = $product->get_sku();
$stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
$price = $product->price;
$imageinfo = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
$imageurl = $imageinfo[0]; // 0 ist die URL
$image = preg_replace($suchmuster, '', $imageurl);
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

$count = 0;
foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
{

    if($count > 12){ 
//  echo 'Nächste Produkt';
        break;
    }

    ${'bild'.$count} = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

    $count += 1;

}

foreach ($categories as $c) {
    $category = $c->name;
}


$inventorydata[] = [
"ean"           => $sku,
"condition"     => "100",
"listing_price" => $price,
"minimum_price" => $price,
"amount"        => $stock,
"delivery_time" => "b",
"location"      => "DE"
];

$productdata[] = [
    "ean"                      => $sku,
    "title"                    => $title,
    "short_description"        => $details,
    "description"              => $description,
    "manufacturer"             => 'Manufaktur13',
    "mpn"                      => '',
    "picture1"                 => $bild0,
    "picture2"                 => $bild1,
    "picture3"                 => $bild2,
    "picture4"                 => $bild3,
    "picture5"                 => $bild4,
    "picture6"                 => $bild5,
    "picture7"                 => $bild6,
    "picture8"                 => $bild7,
    "picture9"                 => $bild8,
    "picture10"                => $bild9,
    "picture11"                => $bild10,
    "picture12"                => $bild11,
    "colour"                   => '',
    "target"                   => 'Unisex',
    "shoe_size"                => ''
];


endwhile;
wp_reset_query();

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($productdata as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.csv');
```

Thanks for any help!
EDIT: Added Image of screwed csv export result
EDIT: Updated Code
[image: Result of CSV Export]

Comment: If you use `"` for the fields like `"a","b","c"` then you ahve to escape all `"` in the values from the array. Also do better `fputcsv($fp, array_values($fields));`

Comment: In the CSV is as first `<pre>Array`that comes from an `print '<pre>';printr_r($array);` why is this in the CSV?? And after seeing the content of `description` you should better use XML instead of CSV (or you have to remove all linebreaks!!! to get the csv work). Complicated and tricky stuff. Hopefully you now 100% how CSV files are working. :-)

Comment: the marketplace is forcing me to use csv upload and i want it as dynamically as possible. I fixed all the    " like you said. the array brackets are gone now but im still missing the cleaned column look :)

Comment: Thats because of the linebreaks in the content, that in the CSV itself are interpreted as real linebreaks not linebreaks of the content. That how linebreaks in CSV files work. I thing that the given data is way too complex for CSV format. But, whatever,  remove all linebreaks `\n` and `\r\n` from the values of the array before adding. `str_replace(["\r\n","\n"],' ',$value);`

Comment: Hopefully you wont have any problems with your UMLAUTs.

Comment: ok i got rid off the line breaks via preg_replace and a search pattern but now my CSV is completly empty but my array is full of data...

Comment: I updated the code (MARKED WITH //EDIT)

Comment: Then fix the regex `preg_replace` cant help here because i dont now what `/-150x150/` will do in the regex.sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the status of this question, it seems like more of an ongoing project than a single concise question.  Anyhow, I'd like to help you get this question resolved.

Your `$image = preg_replace($suchmuster, '', $imageurl);` won't loop through your array of regex patterns.  You can just pipe all the matches you want to replace into a single regex pattern like this:

```
$image=preg_replace('(&nbsp;|\s\s+|-150x150|-300x300|-500x500)','',$imageurl);
```

or if you want better flexibility with managing your code in the future you can do this:

```
$patterns=array("&nbsp;","\s\s+","-150x150","-300x300","-500x500");
$image=preg_replace('/('.implode('|',$patterns).')/','',$imageurl);
```